# How do I get Gradle to sync in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, plugins

I can't test any of my code. I've tried different solutions, and none of them has worked for me. This is the error I get:

.

Build file 'C:\Users\tices\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloWorld\build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:
  Run with the --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

The exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in the 'org.gradle' namespace)
  Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application: com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.3') searched in the following repositories:

  - Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  - Google
  - MavenRepo <152 Internal Lines>

.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe with the new gradle structure, the repositories are in the `settings.gradle` file.

Have you tried to make sure that in your `settings.gradle` file, you have `google()` repository.

Something like this:

```
pluginManagement {
 repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the settings.gradle file? How do I get to it?

Comment: If you are using Android studio as your IDE, the quickest way is through the menu bar.
`Navigate -> Search Everywhere` then search for `settings.gradle` file.

Comment: It ended up syncing itself. All I had to do was click on a "sync gradle" link