# 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to Android studio. The first time I created a new project the IDE started downloading gradle, and afterwards it started to download com.android.application . this part took a lot of time but after some minutes I got this error :

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

My Android studio version is bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3. And I have tried the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71784769/18031488
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72799441/18031488 (I tried a proxy. didn't solve the problem)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71786490/18031488
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71020686/18031488
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403912/18031488
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71097021/18031488

Can I install the plugin manually or is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Sitting behind a company Zscaler Web Gateway terminating all TLS traffic. None of the proposed actions like adding a proxy or other repos, or changing IPv4/IPv6 settings worked.

The solution was:

1. add the Zscaler certificate to Android Studio's JRE cacert keystore. You find it under \jre\lib\security\cacerts.
   Either use the Java keytool \jre\bin\keytool.exe from a Command windows / Shell or a GUI like KeyStoreExplorer. Default password of the keystore is "changeit".
2. After adding the proxy certificate to cacerts, restart AS and now the gradle project build works!

Note: In case your Company security apps are scanning all downloaded stuff, sometimes they can't do that fast enough and you get 403 errors in your IDE for Gradle/Maven sync actions. Repeating the project sync process normally eliminates such errors.

Comment: Well I'm not that familiar with network certificates but I think you meant that my company local network doesn't allow me to use HTTP connection. And I'm on a personal computer and I connect directly to an ISP so I don't think that is the case. BTW thanks for your help