# Easiest way to code/debug in Android studio without Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, build

So a couple of days ago, I decided to start android programming using Android studio. After installing the IDE I had some problems syncing Gradle (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857531/com-android-application-version-7-1-3-apply-false-was-not-found-in-any-o)). Now I'm trying to use Android studio without Gradle. I've read some topics about using Ant etc. but I don't know which one is the easiest way to do that, And most of them weren't talking about Android studio.(note that I want to use Android studio and build/debug apps normally, just like someone who uses Gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is the build system for Android.  Android Studio uses it for all its builds.  You can't build without using Gradle.  There were alternative build systems years ago, but they stopped being supported almost a decade ago now.  While it would be technically possible to build without gradle, you'd be doing months of work to get a basic build up and running because you'd have to rewrite EVERYTHING google's build does using the alternative system.

Basically you can spend a few days figuring out how to fix your gradle setup (which will almost certainly end up being trivial) or you can spend the next year writing a build system. Pick the first option.